# How can I find all duplicate questions asked under a tag?

Tags: support, search

Is it possible to find all duplicate questions asked under a tag per day?

The intention is to find more recently repeated questions and go through their answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following search query:

```
[tag-name] duplicate:1 created:2020-10-17
```

Replace `tag-name` with the name of the tag, and the date there with the date you want to search for in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Alternatively, use `1d` instead of a date to search yesterday's date (in UTC).